# Jquery datepicker doesn't getTime if selected over the 12th

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a datepicker and I am trying to get the time of the date selected, but it only seems to work if the date selected is under the 12th of the month. If you select anything over the 12th it doesn't return a time, does anyone know why?

```js
$('.date-selected').datepicker({
 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
 
onSelect: function(date) {

var cDate = new Date($('.date-selected').val()).getTime();
$(".test-time").text(cDate);

}
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input class="date-selected" value="29/10/2019">
<div class="test-time"></div>
```

Comment: Hint: months in a JavaScript `Date` object start at 0 and end at 11

Comment: While that is something to consider when passing month as a separate parameter, the problem here is that `Date()` was looking for mm/dd/yy while he was providing dd/mm/yy... so it thought that the days were months. You can actually pass "11/22/2019" for example and it will know you mean November.. it's just when you pass as separate parameters that you need to worry about the 0 base for month. IE `("11/22/2019")` = nov 22, 2019, while `(2019, 11, 22)` = Dec 22, 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your date format was just wrong, try `mm/dd/yy`

```js
$('.date-selected').datepicker({
 dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
 
onSelect: function(date) {

var cDate = new Date($('.date-selected').val()).getTime();
$(".test-time").text(cDate);

}
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input class="date-selected" value="29/10/2019">
<div class="test-time"></div>
```

Comment: you can store the date object in a variable and format it after you pull out the time

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your format with the days first, you'll have to convert it to something that `Date()` will understand. A safe bet is just passing year, month, day as separate parameters. You'll also have to subtract 1 from the month as months start at 0 when using the parameters this way.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

```js
$('.date-selected').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
 
  onSelect: function(date) {
    var dateParts = $('.date-selected').val().split('/');
    var cDate = new Date(dateParts[2],dateParts[1]-1,dateParts[0]).getTime();
    $(".test-time").text(cDate + ' = ' + new Date(cDate));
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input class="date-selected" value="29/10/2019">
<div class="test-time"></div>
```